# Issue with CLR package in python

Tags: python

```
import clr
import gc

clr.AddReference('EasyXLS')
from EasyXLS import *
from System.Drawing import *
from EasyXLS.Constants import *

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0890259cfabc> in <module>
      3 import gc
      4 
----> 5 clr.AddReference('EasyXLS')
      6 from EasyXLS import *
      7 from System.Drawing import *

AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. I also tried installing pythonnet it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is pythonnet' package's alias is also 'clr', so you need to uninstall the clr first then install the pythonnet. Following are the commands:

```
pip uninstall clr
pip install pythonnet
```